# How to select all respects in one query?

Tags: laravel

When using Eloquent

`$post = Post::with('user', 'comments')->findOrFail($id)`;

Laravel makes a selection of three requests

```
select * from `posts` where `id` = ? limit 1

select * from `users` where `id` in (?)

select * from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` in (?)
```

Are there any methods that will make just one request?

Comment: As I know this executes the single query. `$post = Post::with('user', 'comments')->findOrFail($id);`

Comment: If you look at the result using the toSql() method, then the query will be only partial

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
 $post = Post::leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            ->where('posts.id', $id)
            ->select('posts.*', 'users.name as commenter_name', 'comments.*')
            ->get();
```